# Why click event listener just once working

Tags: javascript, html, click, addeventlistener

**I want the function to be executed when any li element is clicked. How can I do that?**

```js
var listItem = document.getElementById("listItem");

listItem.addEventListener("click", clickTodo)

function clickTodo() {
  listItem.style.color = "red"
}
```

```css
ul li {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="listItem">One</li>
  <li id="listItem">Two</li>
  <li id="listItem">Other</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use event propagation to set the event handler on the parent element, and then check which child element generated the event using `e.target` to do whatever you would like to do to that element.

Comment: @BlackMath Yes [exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373808/295783)

Comment: You can only have one `id`.

Comment: I STRONGLY suggest you [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373808/295783) instead of looping! Added benefit, you can add new TODOs and the click still works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listItem` should be a `class` instead of an `id` to group all your `li` elements. Then, add the event listener to each item using a `forEach` as follows:

```js
const listItems = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");

[...listItems].forEach(listItem => 
  listItem.addEventListener("click", clickTodo) 
);

function clickTodo() {
  this.style.color = "red"
}
```

```css
ul li {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="listItem">One</li>
  <li class="listItem">Two</li>
  <li class="listItem">Other</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373808/295783)

Comment: This will not run on NEW TODOs added to the list after the code has run

Comment: @Enes It works for a static list. Not if you dynamically add listItems

Answer (score 1):

IDs need to be unique and eventListener on one element works on one element only

It is recommended to delegate from nearest static container

Added benefit, you can add new TODOs and the click still works

I also suggest you use CSS and toggle the class

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");

list.addEventListener("click", clickTodo)

function clickTodo(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("listItem")) tgt.classList.toggle("red");
}
```

```css
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="listItem">One</li>
  <li class="listItem">Two</li>
  <li class="listItem">Other</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id. You should use a class instead.

You can then select all the elements using `document.querySelectorAll` and add event listeners to each of them.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('ul > li.listItem').forEach(li => 
    li.addEventListener('click', clickTodo));

function clickTodo() {
  this.style.color = "red"
}
```

```css
ul li {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="listItem">One</li>
  <li class="listItem">Two</li>
  <li class="listItem">Other</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373808/295783)

Comment: This will not run on NEW TODOs added to the list after the code has run

Comment: Lastly it will not run on earlier EDGE browsers which do not support forEach on html collections

Comment: @mplungjan `forEach` is easily polyfilled.

Comment: @mplungjan I agree that delegation is the way to go with dynamic content, but for only a few elements, it does not really matter.

Comment: It matters in DYNAMIC lists! It does not matter how many items

Comment: @mplungjan This list isn't dynamic. That was the point.

Comment: First todo list I ever saw with static todos

Comment: @mplungjan Perhaps question the asker about that detail instead.

Comment: My solution works in all cases. Why should I need to ask if a todo list is static. Would be the first static todo list I ever saw. Perhaps worth telling us if that was important

Answer (score 0):

And id is supposed to be unique and used on a single element.
If you want to select multiple elements you should use a class instead.
But in that case you can just select elements directly:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => 
    li.addEventListener('click', clickTodo));

function clickTodo() {
  this.style.color = "red"
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373808/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan 's answer is the correct one. I answered too fast :p